# Bootstrap nav-list could not stay expand when pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

Struggle in this question quite some time, i have try through several way to fix this, but there are not hope signed.

code for html:

```
<ul  class="nav nav-list" >
<li class="active"  >
                <a  href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle">
<i class="menu-icon fa fa-sitemap"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text" >
                      Menu
 <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
<ul class="submenu" >
<li class="#" >
                <a href="#"  class="dropdown-toggle">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <span class="menu-text"  > 
                   Burger Choice
 <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
<ul  class="submenu">
                <li class="#" >
<asp:LinkButton  runat="server" id="Burgerset"  onClick="MenuSet_Click"  CommandArgument="Chicken Burger:0">
<i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>&nbsp;BurgetSet
</asp:LinkButton>
</li>
</li>
<ul>
```

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav li a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

How to can make the menu click and the nav-list still keep expand?
so far now only the asp:LinkButton have link with others webpage,
but it will reset back to Menu won't stay inside list link after click.
The way i want is the list will memorized user click.

Comment: Currently, when any user clicks your link the menu section gets expanded and show the details to user but if you press `ctrl` + `F5` then the page gets loaded and menu section is not expanded. Is this your problem ?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal yes , that's right.

Comment: If that's the case then only way I could suggest you to handle them with cookies if handling from client because on reload whole HTML get's reset. Save a bit when user click on menu area, save it on cookie and during reload at DOM ready read from cookie and just like you are expanding on click same way do that on condition. But there's a problem with that too if user visit's that section after some period of time for. e.g. 1hr, 2 hr .. If there's any previous cookie then also the menu will be expanded so if you are using cookie do handle them properly.

Comment: i have consider cookie as an option, because of the menu will be in dynamic, thank you for your suggestion